# iOS 7 iPad white line on dark UITableView

Tags: ipad, ios7

We have a UITableView, where we set the backgrounds to be black in the headers and grey in the cells.  On iOS 6 it works.  On iOS 7 we noticed a white line above each black section heading on the iPad 3rd-gen.  I haven't noticed this on other devices like an iPhone 5.

Is there a workaround to remove this white line?  Is this a bug in iPad?

Comment: you can change your cell frame .. like y=-1;

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug with iOS 7, try highlighting the cell above the section and scrolling so you don't call your didSelectRow method, and you will see that the separator picks up the style after that...